# opening another python 3 process from subprocess.Popen is setting locale default encoding to ANSI_X3.4-1968 but only in certain instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, subprocess

This is driving me nuts.  I have a main python 3 (3.5.2) driver/program that I use subprocess and popen with to spawn additional python 3 processes that I communicate with using rpyc.  This has been working well, especially in python 2.

I've successfully converted to python 3 and have verified that all of these processes spawn successfully if run from a terminal.

To launch them from my driver, it looks like this.

```
cmd_one = "/path/to/.virtualenv/venv_one/bin/python file_a.py"
cmd_two = "/path/to/.virtualenv/venv_two/bin/python file_b.py"
s_one = subprocess.Popen(cmd_one.split(), stdout=logfile, stderr=logfile)
s_two = subprocess.Popen(cmd_two.split(), stdtou=logfile, stderr=logfile)
```

This worked great in Python 2.7.

As I upgrade to Python 3, however, I'm seeing something weird with default encoding that I can't figure.  For cmd_one, it works great-- if I do a

```
import locale
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
```

it returns `UTF-8` like I'd expect.  However, for cmd_two, I am getting `ANSI_X3.4-1968` for seemingly no reason, and it's throwing a boatload of unicodedecode errors as a result.  Like I said, when spawned in the terminal both cmd_one and cmd_two work great and use the proper default encoding.

I've searched extensively but this seems to be a special case.  I don't want to force the default encoding because I feel like that is masking some other issue.  Is there something in the `file_b.py` and its constituents that is somehow setting the encoding to ANSII when it doesn't see that it's run in the terminal?  `file_b.py` is part of a large Tensorflow project, and there are about 8 files it draw upon but I've looked in all of them but can't find anything.

This is on `ubuntu 16.04` and the default python 3 is 3.5.2, and as far as I know, there's no way to pass `encoding='utf-8'` with Popen.

Any suggestions on what the heck is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: you can pass encoding when you're opening `logfile`...

Comment: changed popen to Popen (sorry @Jean-FrançoisFabre)

Comment: good, now check my second comment :)

Comment: the issue is the default encoding of the python environment-- it's not throwing an error on writing to the logfile. i'm doing a ton of machine learinng NLP string/text stuff and I need the default encoding to be utf-8 (which is the python3 default) or it breaks everything.  Something is changing that somewhere to ascii when i open it as a subprocess, and only in that one instance, I can't figure out where.

Comment: I'm not an encoding expert. Have an upvote & good luck with your question

Answer (score 1):

OP here, I think I found a solution but I still don't know why I need to do this only for this specific instance-- hopefully, somebody can weigh in so that I can understand this better.

From:

https://webkul.com/blog/setup-locale-python3/

When I run:

`locale`

in my terminal and as a subprocess, I get:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

What fixed the default encoding for me was to set the locale environment `LANGUAGE` to `en_US.en` and `LC_ALL` to `en_US.UTF-8` variables, and pass them directly to the subprocess with Popen.

```
s = subprocess.Popen(cmd_two.split(), env={'LANGUAGE':'en_US.en', 'LC_ALL':'en_US.UTF-8'})
```

Now it properly identifies the default encoding as `UTF-8` in my subprocess and everything works.

Can anybody explain this to me?  I don't need to do this with my other subprocess and it works just fine.

Comment: Using ```env={'LANGUAGE':'en_US.en', 'LC_ALL':'en_US.UTF-8'}``` fixed my issue as well. Thank you very much